# Pytesseract Image to String issue

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Does anyone know how I can get these results better?

[image]

```
Total Kills: 15,230,550

Kill Details: (recorded after 2019/10,/Z3]

993,151 331,129
1,330,450 33,265,533
5,031,168
```

This is what it returns however it is meant to be the same as the image posted below, I am new to python so are there any parameters that I  can add to make it read the image better?

```
img = cv2.imread("kills.jpeg")

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    print(text)
```

This is my code to read the image, Is there anything I can add to make it read better? Also, the black boxes are to cover images that were interfering with the reading. I would like to also say that I have added the 2 black boxes to see if the images behind them were causing the issue, but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing knowledge is [page-segmentation-mode](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) (psm). You need to use them, when you can't get the desired result.

If we look at your image, the only artifacts are the black columns. Other than that, the image looks like a binary image. Suitable for tesseract to recognize the characters and the digits.

Lets try reading the image by setting the psm to 6.

> 6    Assume a single uniform block of text.

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="--psm 6")
```

The result will be:

```
Total Kills: 75,230,550

Kill Details: (recorded after 2019/10/23)
993,161 331,129
1,380,450 33,265,533
5,031,168
```

Update

---

The second way to solve the problem is getting binary mask and applying OCR to the mask features.

- Binary-mask

  - [image]
- Features of the binary-mask

  - [image]

As we can see the result is slightly different from the input image. Now when we apply OCR [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9d46.jpg) will be:

```
Total Kills: 75,230,550

Kill Details: (recorded after 2019/10/23)
993,161 331,129
1,380,450 33,265,533
5,031,168
```

---

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("LuKz3.jpg")

# Convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get the binary mask
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([179, 255, 154]))

# Extract
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config="--psm 6")
print(txt)

# Display
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply however I have changed it to the above but I still get the same result, Do you think resizing the image would help?

Comment: What is  your pytesseract version?

Comment: tesseract 3.02 - It shows this version when I run tesseract -v

Comment: But, if I'm not mistaken the latest version is (4.1.1) [0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/). Could you please update your version to the latest?

Comment: Yeah, Let me do that and I will retry and then post back here thank you

Comment: Yeah sorry, I do have the correct version as you posted above. But for some reason, I just get the same results.

Comment: Ok, then let me find another way to solve

Comment: It is now changing the numbers to letters or returning the wring result, Also thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see the answer under Update-1. Your result should be similar the [answer](https://imgur.com/a/G7MkSfq).

Comment: Glad to help, so the second solution works?

Comment: It made the results a lot better, but a few numbers were incorrect. I think it is to do with the size of the image. Some people have said making the image bigger will make the result better. I just need to work out how to do it.

Comment: Ok then give it a try, hopr you find the desired solution. But I really don't understand the reason, why don't have the exact same solution. If you want to see my result, you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/G7MkSfq)

Comment: Hello, I am curious how you did it because I have copied the same as you but mine is incorrect.

`Total Kills: 15,230,550

Kill Details: (recorded after 2019/10/23)





993,151 331,129
1,330,450

5,031,153

33,255,533`
This is the result I get.